# How to get the file location inside a project?

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

I'm currently using a JSON file namely ***products.json*** for writing a keyword search app. I put the file inside the package ***com.search.api.dao*** as shown in the image.

[image]

I read the data inside the constructor of ***ProductsDAO.java*** class using the following code,

```
public ProductsDAO() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    URL path = ProductsDAO.class.getResource("products.json");
    File myFile = new File(path.getFile());
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(myFile));

    JSONObject js = (JSONObject) obj;
    jsonArray = (JSONArray) js.get("products");

}
```

As you see, I created ***data*** folder inside the ***src*** and put the ***products.json*** file there. The full location path here is "***/ProductSearch/src/data/products.json***". How can I read the file from this location ? I tried it both relative and absolute paths and none of them is not working.

Comment: `URL path = ProductsDAO.class.getResource("/data/products.json")` or `URL path = ProductsDAO.class.getResource("data/products.json")`.  Don't include `src` in your paths, anywhere

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works fine.